# Recursive functions to render data till nth level of nesting react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, algorithm, object

```
    const data = [
  {
    "laboaratory": [
      {
        "status": {
          display: "Code",
          value: "23123"
        },
        "observation": [
          {
            display: "Code",
            value: "23123"
          }
        ],
        "resultValue": {
          "quantity": [
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ],
          "codeableConcept": [
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            },
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "status": {
          display: "Code",
          value: "23123"
        },
        "observation": [
          {
            display: "Code",
            value: "23123"
          }
        ],
        "resultValue": {
          "quantity": [
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ],
          "codeableConcept": [
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            },
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "medications": [
      {
        "status": {
          display: "medications - Code",
          value: "23123"
        },
        "resultValue": {
          "quantity": [
            {
              display: "medications- Code",
              value: "23123"
            },
            {
              display: "medications-Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ],
          "codeableConcept": [
            {
              display: "medications-Code",
              value: "23123"
            },
            {
              display: "medications- Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "status": {
          display: "medications - Code",
          value: "23123"
        },
        "resultValue": {
          "quantity": [
            {
              display: "medications- Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ],
          "codeableConcept": [
            {
              display: "medications-Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "status": {
          display: "medications - Code",
          value: "23123"
        },
        "resultValue": {
          "quantity": [
            {
              display: "medications- Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ],
          "codeableConcept": [
            {
              display: "medications-Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Data Dipslay Format in UI** (HTML View with accordion header and table data and where we can open and close the accordion)

```
-> Laboratory(Main Heading) <h1> Laboratory<h1/>
   -> status (Sub-heading) <h3>stats<h3/>
       Code - 23123 (table data) <table><th>Code</th><tr></tr>23123<table/>
   -> observation (Sub-heading)
        code - 1232 (table data)
        code -12312
   -> ResultValue (Sub-heading)
         -> quantity (Sub -sub heading)
           code - 1232 (table data)
           code -12312
         -> codeableConcept (Sub -sub heading)
           code - 1232 (table data)
           code -12312

-> medications(Main Heading)
   -> status (Sub-heading)
       medications-Code - 23123 (table data)
   -> observation (Sub-heading)
        medications-code - 1232 (table data)
        medications-code -12312
   -> ResultValue (Sub-heading)
         -> quantity (Sub -sub heading)
           medications-code - 1232 (table data)
           medications-code -12312
         -> codeableConcept (Sub -sub heading)
           medications-code - 1232 (table data)
           medications-code -12312
```

[image]
How can we display the data in UI by using above datasets ,it might have more nested data .I have to write a generic recursive code while can handle dynamic data rendering in UI without breaking ? The above structure should be like tree structure with accordion so that we can open and close the class and its related sub classes .(Just like a DOM tree like data structure) .Let me know if any further details are needed.
the data will be rendered in HTML view .

I tried using map to render the data its is becoming nested and its not generic .How can we handle data till nth level by using recursion and show in UI ?

```
data.map((data) => {
  Object.keys(data).map((header) => {
    //console.log(header)
    data[header].map((headerData) => {
      if(Array.isArray(data[header])) {
          //console.log(headerData)
      }  else {
          console.log(headerData)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

And how can we handle pagination for every keys(laboratory ,medications) if any of the key is having more than one object ?(Attached screenshot below on how pagination will look on class level)

Comment: What is your UI (console? HTML doc? ...) and what have you tried?

Comment: @trincot IT will be a HTML view

Comment: And what is holding you back from doing it? You've tagged with `reactjs`, but I don't see anything related to react in your question.

Comment: I am not able to write the recursive logic which can handle data till nth level @trincot

Comment: I don't really understand what your output should be like. Your code attempt only has `console.log` and your data display section has a mix of bracketed text, `h1` and `h3` tags, invalid `table` structures, a requirement to have accordion features... That is unclear and honestly too broad. Please focus your question an a specific problem. If the problem is with recursion, then drop all of the UI specifics from your question and focus on producing the most simple structure (no accordion, no mix of tags, tables, ...etc). There should be just one problem to solve in your question, not 10.

Answer (score 0):

I made this recursive component which seems to achieve what you want. Of course it is up to you to style it properly :

```js
function RecursiveComponent({ content, level = 1 }) {
    const Header = `h${ level }`

    if (Array.isArray(content))
        return <>{ content.map((e, i) => <RecursiveComponent content={e} key={i} level={level} />) }</>

    if (typeof content === 'object') {
        if (content.display && content.value)
            return <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '1em', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <span>{ content.display }</span>
                <span>{ content.value }</span>
            </div>

        return <>{
            Object.keys(content).map(key => 
                <div key={key}>
                    <Header>{ key }</Header>
                    {<RecursiveComponent content={content[key]} level={level + 1} />}
                </div>
            )
        }</>
    }

    return <span>{ content }</span>
}
```

Hope it helped you !

Comment: One more things I want to handle in the above scenarios is pagination .What will be the correct way of doing it ?In case any keys is having more than 1 objects ,then we have to show pagination and on change of page we have show that respective object  based on index .

Comment: Do you want pagination only for top level ?
And what would the objects and the pages you want look like ?

Comment: Pagination will be applicable to only top level classes like medication ,laboratory. 
Laboratory  = index-0 {}, index- 1 ={} ,index={} .You can simply copy the first object for laboratory and medication and create more object under that ,that should be the json structure.and at the top right corner there will a arrow keys like the above screenshot

Comment: Does my new answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood accurately what you wanted, this seems to do the job :

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const data = [
  {
    "laboaratory": [
      {
        "status": {
          display: "Code",
          value: "23123"
        },
        "observation": [
          {
            display: "Code",
            value: "23123"
          },
          {
            display: "Code",
            value: "23123"
          }
        ],
        "resultValue": {
          "quantity": [
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            },
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ],
          "codeableConcept": [
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            },
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "status": {
          display: "Code",
          value: "Value on page 2"
        },
        "observation": [
          {
            display: "Code",
            value: "Value on page 2"
          },
          {
            display: "Code",
            value: "Value on page 2"
          }
        ],
        "resultValue": {
          "quantity": [
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "Value on page 2"
            },
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "Value on page 2"
            }
          ],
          "codeableConcept": [
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "Value on page 2"
            },
            {
              display: "Code",
              value: "Value on page 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "medications": [
      {
        "status": {
          display: "medications - Code",
          value: "23123"
        },
        "observation": [
          {
            display: "medications -Code",
            value: "23123"
          },
          {
            display: "medications- Code",
            value: "23123"
          }
        ],
        "resultValue": {
          "quantity": [
            {
              display: "medications- Code",
              value: "23123"
            },
            {
              display: "medications-Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ],
          "codeableConcept": [
            {
              display: "medications-Code",
              value: "23123"
            },
            {
              display: "medications- Code",
              value: "23123"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "status": {
          display: "medications - Code",
          value: "Medication value on page 2"
        },
        "observation": [
          {
            display: "medications -Code",
            value: "Medication value on page 2"
          },
          {
            display: "medications- Code",
            value: "Medication value on page 2"
          }
        ],
        "resultValue": {
          "quantity": [
            {
              display: "medications- Code",
              value: "Medication value on page 2"
            },
            {
              display: "medications-Code",
              value: "Medication value on page 2"
            }
          ],
          "codeableConcept": [
            {
              display: "medications-Code",
              value: "Medication value on page 2"
            },
            {
              display: "medications- Code",
              value: "Medication value on page 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

function App() {
    return <RecursiveComponent content={data} />
}

function PaginatedComponent ({ content, level }) {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
    const l = content.length - 1;

    return <>
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setPage(page => page - 1)} disabled={page === 0}>{'<'}</button>
            <span>{ page + 1 } / { l + 1 }</span>
            <button onClick={() => setPage(page => page + 1)} disabled={page === l}>{'>'}</button>
        </div>

        <RecursiveComponent level={level + 1} content={content[page]}></RecursiveComponent>
    </>
}

function RecursiveComponent({ content, level = 1, paginated = level === 1 }) {
    const Header = `h${ level }`

    if (Array.isArray(content))
        return <>{ content.map((e, i) => <RecursiveComponent content={e} key={i} level={level} />) }</>

    if (paginated)
        return <>{
            Object.keys(content).map(key =>
                <div key={key}>
                    <Header>{ key }</Header>
                    <PaginatedComponent key={key} content={content[key]} level={level} />
                </div>
            )
        }</>

    if (typeof content === 'object') {
        if (content.display && content.value)
            return <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '1em', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <span>{ content.display }</span>
                <span>{ content.value }</span>
            </div>

        return <>{
            Object.keys(content).map(key => 
                <div key={key}>
                    <Header>{ key }</Header>
                    <RecursiveComponent content={content[key]} level={level + 1} />
                </div>
            )
        }</>
    }

    return <span>{ content }</span>
}
```

Hope it helped you !